# How to map controllers from application part to subpath?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, modular-monolith

I define modules for my app, and I add resources as [application parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to the application.

However, I'd like to map all endpoints from each module to its own subpath.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you kindly check the solution below ? Please let me know if it works for you,many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can implement this requirementby using `IApplicationModelConvention`. You can check the test result first and tell me is it you want([I am using the official repo](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/mvc/advanced/app-parts/sample2)).

[image]

**If this is what you want to achieve, please follow my steps.**

**Step 1. Download the repo and create ModuleRoutingConvention.cs file.**

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;

namespace AppPartsSample
{
    public class ModuleRoutingConvention : IApplicationModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
        {
            foreach (var controller in application.Controllers)
            {
                var namespaceParts = controller.ControllerType.Namespace?.Split('.');
                if (namespaceParts != null && (namespaceParts.Contains("DependentLibrary") || namespaceParts.Contains("Plugin")))
                {
                    var moduleName = namespaceParts[0];

                    foreach (var selector in controller.Selectors.Where(s => s.AttributeRouteModel != null).ToList())
                    {
                        selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel()
                        {
                            Template = $"{moduleName}/{selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template}"
                        };
                    }
                    foreach (var selector in controller.Selectors.Where(s => s.AttributeRouteModel == null).ToList())
                    {
                        selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel()
                        {
                            Template = $"{moduleName}/[controller]/[action]"
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2. Modify the EntityTypes.cs file, like below.**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AppPartsSample.Model
{
    #region snippet
    public static class EntityTypes
    {
        public static IReadOnlyList<TypeInfo> Types => new List<TypeInfo>()
        {
            typeof(Features).GetTypeInfo(),
            typeof(Home).GetTypeInfo(),
            typeof(NoGood).GetTypeInfo(),
            typeof(Hello).GetTypeInfo(),
        };

        public class Features { }
        public class Home { }

        public class NoGood { }
        public class Hello { }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Step 3. Register it in your Startup.cs

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       //services.AddMvc()
       //        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
       //        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
       //            apm.FeatureProviders.Add(new GenericControllerFeatureProvider()));

       services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
       {
           apm.FeatureProviders.Add(new GenericControllerFeatureProvider());
       }).AddMvcOptions(options =>
       {
           options.Conventions.Add(new ModuleRoutingConvention());
       });
   }
```

**Step 4. Add attributes on the controllers in your Class Library Project.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply separate base controllers and customize their routes.
With this you can limit authorizations and produce consume types as well.

**Base Controller**

```
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Consumes(ApiContentTypes.ApplicationJson)]
[Produces(ApiContentTypes.ApplicationJson)]
public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
{

}
```

**Employee Module Base Controller**

```
[Route("api/EmployeeModule/[Controller]/[Action]")]
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.EmployeeAdmin)]
public class EmployeeModuleController : BaseApiController 
{

}
```

**Employee Module Sub-Controllers**

```
public class ManagerEmployeeController : EmployeeModuleController
{

}
```

**Another module base controller**

```
[Route("api/Story")]
public class StoryModuleController : BaseApiController 
{

}
```

**Sub-base controller**

```
[Route("Instagram/[Action]")]
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.InstagramPolicy)]
public class InstagramStoryController : StoryModuleController
{
   public async Task<IResponse> GetAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
   {
      await Task.Yield();
      return new SuccessResponse("Successfully Retrieved");
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a pragmatic approach. I'd rather extract the segment into some constant, so it's easy to set it to empty string or other value when module is moved somewhere else. But it's not perfect, IMO, because segment assignment should be the responsibility of the host application, not module itself.

Comment: Although I do not see them as cross cutting concern, I keep them in the core project and give sdk reference. In this way, even if there are 100 different modules or projects, I can reference them in a way that does not disrupt the modular monolith structure. I agree that it is a pragmatic approach, but it is a very common approach in the company I work for.